# Maven assembly plugin not building files from descriptor

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am trying to create a `tar.gz` with the name `my-project-2.0.tar.gz` and inside that file there is a `zip` file with all my java classes called `my-project.zip`. The reason for this is due to some script files that look for this type of format.

I have set up the maven assembly plug in my `pom` file and the descriptor files.

This issue is that when I run my build the plug in and descriptors are ignored.

The goal in eclipse is `clean package`.

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>assemble</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/prep.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>bundle</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>my-project-2.0</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/bundle.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This is the bundle descriptor:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bundle-id</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>my-project.zip</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/assembly</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>place.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This is the prep descriptor

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>prep-id</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Ive tried running `clean assembly:assembly` but I get a `No assembly descriptors found' error

Ive tried rewritting my plug in as:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>my-project-2.0</finalName>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/bundle.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>assemble</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I dont know how to name the inside `zip` as `my-project.zip`

Answer (score 0):

When the zip file is created with `prep.xml` the name of the zip file should be `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip`.

So in your case my-project-${project.version}.zip.

Try to edit the `bundle.xml` the following way:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>target</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>my-project-${project.version}.zip</include>
  </includes>
  <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why my build was ignoring my descriptors is because I had all my plugins wrapped around a `<pluginManagement> </pluginManagement>`.

This solved my issue